# Find out what adaptor power socket an unopened iPhone 5s has

Tags: power, iphone

I have an unboxed iPhone5s here, which I have received as a gift from a friend who also received it as a gift and did not want it. I might end up regifting it myself, so I would rather not open it.

How can I find out what adapter power socket it has included? (I am thinking it may either be German or British).

The codes on the back read:

ZP862-1643-A

Part No. MF353ZP/A

Serial No. C35LRVTGFRC5

IMEI/MEID 358693055033047

The barcode starts with 8 and the outer packaging has text in English and Chinese.

Comment: MF353ZP/A is Location of Purchase: Hong Kong, but it doesn't specify what power socket it would be.

Comment: Can't I use the device code to find out more about the device?

Comment: I'd go to http://store.apple.com for your country and just ask them to help you determine what model you got gifted. The phone / web support is excellent for pre and post sales. They might also be able to tell you the carrier it was sold to and lock status.

Comment: Oh, great, Apple doesn't want to chat with me because I'm outside the US :-/